# TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so in my module.js, I put

```js
        function emoji(e) {
            return client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === e)
        } 

        module.exports = {
            emoji
        }
```

and in index,js, I put

```js
    const module = require("./module.js")

    msg.react(module.emoji('check'))
```

So what I'm making is that I want the bot to react with a custom emoji I uploaded named **'check'**. In case I could use this in the future, I decided to make a function so that the bot(client) can find emoji easily without me copy/pasting "client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === blabla)" everytime when needed.

But when I run it, the console says
`TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji`

The reason why I'm posting this is because when I put that function block into **index.js**, it **works perfectly**. But when I put it into module.js and use it by module exporting, the error occurs as I mentioned.

Can anyone tell me what I missed?

Comment: Not sure about this, but try doing `const { emoji } = require("./module.js")` instead of `const module = require("./module.js")`

Comment: it says "emoji is declared but its value is never read" and occurs same error

Comment: Could you edit this to have the full files in the code? or at least all the relevant information in the files (not just the actual problem code, but the code surrounding the problem)

Comment: If you need help how to create a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tested this, but i have a few things I think you should try:

1. What Elitezen suggested, which is specifically requiring the emoji function from the module:

`const { emoji } = require("./module")`

2. what would also probably work is just to do

```
module.exports = emoji //instead of module.exports = { emoji }
```

^^ this means it only exports the emoji function, instead of exporting a dictionary containing the function.

After my edits, your full code would look like this:

```
function emoji(e, client) {
    return client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === e)
} 
module.exports = emoji
```

```
const module = require("./module.js")

msg.react(module('check', client))
```

Comment: The console says "TypeError: module.emoji is not a function".

Comment: When you call it, you need to just do module()

your code would look like this:

`const module = require("./module.js")

 msg.react(module('check'))`

Comment: Hmm. But now it says "TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji". I assume these errors are being occurred from module exporting because as I explained above, it works normally when I just put the function into 'index.js'. Do you agree  with me?

Comment: This error is caused by you trying to react to the message with something that isnt actually an emoji, so I think this is caused by the name of the emoji not being correct. as far as I know, 'check' isn't actually an emoji in discord. try using `'white_check_mark'`

Comment: still same error. I don't think it's caused by its name. but, about the part which you've mentioned that the 'check' isnt actually an emoji, and the console error message which says the emoji isnt "string", I think the error might be occurred while exporting 'e' from module.js to index.js, or something like that. function parameter error?

Comment: i just noticed that you don't declare client at all in the `module.js` file. you should try adding another parameter `client` into the function. this might work, since client could be incorrect. also, you might want to try surrounding your code in an async function, and then awaiting the function.

Comment: i have provided an example in my original response.